# unityで"GC overhead limit exceeded"

Tags: android, java, unity3d

Mac OS X 10.9.5、
Unity 4.5.5
を利用しています。

Androidビルド時に、

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.
java -Xmx1024M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="/Applications/android-sdk/tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "(Unityのパス).app/Contents/BuildTargetTools/AndroidPlayer/sdktools.jar" -
```

と出てエラーとなります。

エラーを下っていくと、

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

と出ています。
どなたか、同じようなエラーが発生した方、いらっしゃいますでしょうか？

Comment: 自己解決しました。

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173894/gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-after-adding-a-dependency

こちら参考にして編集し、
Unityを立ち上げ直すと、無事ビルドが通りました。

Comment: ご自分で回答をつけてマークしておくと後にググった時とかに出てきやすきなりますよー